# mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to follow a YouTube tutorial to build a CMS. I am starting to get really confused about the error messages it's creating. I get the following error

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a8241081/public_html/index.php on line 7

Is my code right? Should there be a mysqli_select statement?

```
<?php
$db_host = "********";
$db_username = "******"; 
$db_pass = "*******"; 
$db_name = "********";
mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass", "$db_name") or die ("could not connect to mysql");  
?>
```

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";

//Build Main Navigation menu and gather page data here
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id, linklabel FROM pages ORDER BY pageorder ASC";
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sqlCommand);

$menuDisplay='';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $pid=$row["id"];
    $linklabel=$row["linklabel"];
    
    $menuDisplay .='<a href="index.php?pid=' . $pid . '">' . $linklabel . '</a><br/>';
    
  }
  mysqli_free_result($query);
  //mysqli_close($myConnection); 
?>
```

Comment: When will people finally stop quoting their variables?

Answer (score 9):

You should assign the result of `mysqli_connect()` to a variable:

```
$myConnection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name) or die ("could not connect to mysql");
```

In your current code $myConnection isn't defined in this call :

```
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand);
```